# Paging with ui-routing. Back (next) browser button doesn't reload controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, html5-history

First, I need to say I'm new in front-end developing, so answer in details will be a very helpfully. I'm trying to use ui-routing for paging issue. In fact, I want to add query params to the url. This is my code:

```
angular.module('simpleApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router'
]).config(function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {   
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks: false
    });    

$stateProvider.state('productList', {
    url: '?page',
    controller: 'productPartialController',        
    params: {
        page: {
            value: '1',
            squash: true
        }
    }
});
```

}); 
As you can see, it's initialization. 
This is a part of controller logic:

```
angular.module('simpleApp')
    .controller('productPartialController', ['$scope', 'productService', 'productPartialService', '$compile', '$sce', '$window', '$timeout', '$stateParams', '$state', function ($scope, productService, productPartialService, $compile, $sce, $window, $timeout, $stateParams, $state) {
     var p = parseInt($stateParams.page);
     console.log(p);
     $scope.processQuery = function (page) {
        if (page)
            $scope.pagerSettings.CurrentPage = page;   
productPartialService.getFilterPageData({  
            /*ajax params*/
            sortBy: $scope.pagerSettings.SortBy,              
            currentPage: $scope.pagerSettings.CurrentPage,  
        }).success(function (products) {
            $scope.products = products;
            processProducts();
            calculatePages();
            utils.ToTopScroll();
            if(page)
                $state.go('productList', { page: $scope.pagerSettings.CurrentPage }, { notify: false });

            console.log($stateParams.page);
    });       


    };      
}]);
```

I'm trying to add feature for `non rest` project and loading pages with some url (for example `helloworldsite.loc/phones/samsung`). When I process paging url change as expected  `helloworldsite.loc/phones/samsung?page=4 (if $scope.pagerSettings.CurrentPage is 4), helloworldsite.loc/phones/samsung?page=3 (when $scope.pagerSettings.CurrentPage is 3), etc`. I need to say that I want to use this code for different pages (pages will have different `urls` - helloworldsite.loc/phones/samsung, helloworldsite.loc/accessories, etc), so url should be absolute, as I understand. The problem happens when I try to click on `back-next` browser buttons. It's important I tried to use this sample: http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/20/simple-pagination-and-url-params-with-ui-router/ and the code sample https://gist.github.com/abyx/f5ef04d807dc15617331  You can check and this sample is working perfect. I mean that controller reloads when I click on `back-next` browser buttons, but my controller doesn't. Also, when I try to get inital param (

```
params: {
            page: {
                value: '1',
                squash: true
            }
        }
```

) I receive `NoN` instead of `1`. What am I doing wrong? Could anyone explain me how `state` should work? I've read a part of documentation and really confused about `ui-routing` and `History API` in general and about `History API` in `angular.js` context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

`$state.go('productList', { page: $scope.pagerSettings.CurrentPage }, { notify: false });`

`notify: false` prevents the `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` events from being fired, so that the state will never reload. If you remove `notify: false`, the back and next buttons should work as expected, because UI-Router works with the window history by default.

`notify: false` is something of an anti-pattern in UI-Router that should be avoided unless you have no other choice. This is a quote directly from the UI-Router maintainer on Github:

> Using notify: false is an ugly workaround because of lack of "dynamic
>   params" in 0.2.x and I can't comment on a good way to use it (hint: I
>   would never use it myself)

By default, a UI-Router state has `reloadOnSearch` set to `true`, which means that when a query parameter changes, the state is automatically reloaded.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, but it doesn't help. Removed {notify: false} and nothing changed(((